# How to check whether an element name contains a specific string?

Tags: xslt, xpath

The source document like this:

```
<a>
 <b n=n1n1n1n1>
 <c1> drftgy </c1>
 </b>
<c2> dddd </c2>
</a>
```

---

how to check if the element name = c then we will do something...

Answer (score 7):

**Use a number of standard XPath functions**:

- **[`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name)**
- **[`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)**
- **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)**
- **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with)** (XPath 2.0 only)

To find if the current node's name starts with the string `"c"` use:

```
starts-with(name(), 'c')
```

To find if the current node's name contains the string `"c"` use:

```
contains(name(), 'c')
```

To select all elements in the XML document, whose names start with `"c"` use:

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'c')]
```

To select all elements in the XML document, whose names contain `"c"` use:

```
//*[contains(name(), 'c')]
```

**Edit**: The OP has asked an additional question: How to select all elements whose name is one in a set of names?

**XPath 2.0**:

```
  //*[name(.)= ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')]
```

This uses the *general comparison operator* `=` and selects all elements in the document whose name is one of the strings in the *sequence* `('c1', 'c2', 'c3')`.

This cannot be done only with XPath 1.0,

**XSLT 1.0 + XPath 1.0**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <my:names>
  <name>c1</name>
  <name>c2</name>
  <name>c3</name>
 </my:names>

 <xsl:variable name="vNames" select=
  "document('')/*/my:names/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//*[name()=$vNames]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<a>
 <b n="n1n1n1n1">
 <c1> drftgy </c1>
 </b>
<c2> dddd </c2>
</a>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<c1> drftgy </c1>
<c2> dddd </c2>
```

Comment: thank you, and how to check with multiple values. For example: there are a lot kinds of tag c. So I wanna check for some not all. And the expression look like this:
//*[contains(name(), 'c1') or contains(name(), 'c2') or contains(name(), 'c3')]

Instead of, 
//*[contains(name(), 'c1'|'c2'|'c3')]

Which one is possible? and is there another solutions?

Comment: @user402802: I have added to my answer the solution to your last question expressed in your comment.

Comment: +1 for extend answer, specs link and XPath version distinction.

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 you could use `//*[local-name() = ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')]` or you could use matches with a regular expression e.g. `//*[matches(local-name(), '^c[123]$')]`.